# Question about note speed in Chopin C# minor Nocturne

Tags: piano, rhythm

This is from Chopin, Nocturne in C sharp minor sheet music, Is 1 e slower than the triplet?

[image: Chopin Nocturne in C# minor, mm. 51-53]

Answer (score 1):

Other way around. The two sixteenth notes forming "& a" will be a bit slower.

The circled triplet lasts 1/2 beat (so each note in it lasts 1/6 beat), and the following two notes together last 1/2 beat (so 1/4 beat each).